# Linked Arrays Java - Displaying int and String?

Tags: java, arrays

The task is to organize and display user input corresponding to the marks.

For example,

> Name: Oscar Mark: 25, Name: Rubin Mark:45, Name: Jake Mark:13

So it should display:

```
Rubin 45
Oscar 25
Jake 13
```

The current code only displays the names and marks, but not in an arranged order.
I suspect it may have to do with the `int` and `String`, but I'm not entirely sure.

```
private void btnEnterActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        ArrNames[i] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a Name:");
        ArrMarks[i] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a    mark:"));  
    }      
}                                        

private void btnSortActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    for (int i = 0; i < 5 - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = i +1; j < 5; j++) {
            if (ArrNames[i].compareTo(ArrNames[j]); //>0 sorts in ascending          order  <0 sorts in descending order ==0 tests for duplicate string value
            //using .compareTo because checking 2 names
            {
               //sorting the names
               String temp = ArrNames[i];
               ArrNames[i] = ArrNames[j];
               ArrNames[j] = temp;

               //sorting the marks
               int temp1 = ArrMarks[i];
               ArrMarks[i] = ArrMarks[j];
               ArrMarks[j] = temp1;       
            }     
        }   
    }
}                                       

private void btnDisplayActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
         txaDisplay.append(ArrNames[i] + "\t\t" + ArrMarks[i] + "\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: I would strongly recommend creating a class for `StudentResult` or something similar, which has both the name *and* the mark in. Then you only need one collection. You should also make your code easier to read by formatting it...

Comment: Our teacher doesn't really want us getting involved with classes, I mean this should just require a minor change. The way we were taught is that we need a for loop for basically anything; I know it may sound silly or stupid to some more seasoned programmers but I'm still learning and just need help with a school task

Comment: Wow. That's appalling. So they're happy to get you creating complicated GUIs (import statements would greatly simplify your code, btw) but not use one of the core parts of Java? Eek. Okay, well in that case, I would strongly advise you to extract the *relevant* part of this code (to do with the sorting) from this nearly-200-line GUI into a short but complete console app, so you can focus on *just* that part. Then look at how you're sorting - at the moment you're comparing *names*, not marks...

Comment: This is just generated code from a GUI builder, probably NetBeans'. It's even hidden in the IDE by default.

Comment: @Aru Yes I am using NetBeans it is the program we use in school, sorry about that. I extracted 3 parts which I coded to make it easier.

Comment: As per your question, you say you want to sort based on marks, but then why are you comparing names  `if(ArrNames[i].compareTo(ArrNames[j])>0);`, try comparing marks array

Comment: @ShrikantHavale it does not allow me to use the Marks array

Comment: what do you mean, it doesn't allow to use, did u tried this `if (ArrMarks[i] < ArrMarks[j])` instead of your if conditions

Comment: @ShrikantHavale thats it! works, perfect! Only thing is I used the < sign rather than the > . Otherwise it works, problem solved

Answer (score 5):

The correct solution to the question is to replace

```
if (ArrNames[i].compareTo(ArrNames[j]))
```

with

```
if (ArrMarks[i] < ArrMarks[j])
```

I was originally comparing the names, rather than the actual integer values of the Marks.

Answer (score 2):

Your requirements say that you want it ordered by `mark`, and yet you compare by `name`.